# Modify a file via a script with special rights

Tags: linux, sh, setuid

Probably this is elementary.. Yet I didn't find an explanation to what's happening..
I have these files with these specific rights:

[image: IMG:]

So modtp2 is a shell script I'm using to change tp2 content with a user called "user1" who doesn't belong to the group "SYS":

**modtp2 script**

[image: IMG:]

I changed the user to "user1" and tried to execute the script but I always get this error:

[image: IMG:]

However, according to what I know, it should be executed because even if the SUID is not set correctly, the SGID is. Therefore, the effective GID should be SYS's GID while executing the script which has the right of writing into tp2.

I know it's a wrong explanation since the permission was denied but can you please correct me? Is the effective GID thing applicable only to the current script and not the text file?

Comment: An easy way to debug this is to insert `id` into your script, so you can see the effective uid/gid. Also, if this is a SELlinux system, things can get more complicated. (BTW: You can format code or errors in your question with four leading blanks; links to images are discouraged, OTOH because they are images, OTOH they won't stick around for the next person with the same problem who reads your question).

Comment: By using the debug with the `id` way you've suggested I found that  the user1's GID is the one printed.. Thanks for that and for your precious advice.

Comment: Still when I've disabled SeLlinux I get the same problem.

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2910/108618)?

Comment: What are the flags on the parent directory? Creating a file requires write rights on its parent, for instance.

Comment: I've tried to use a c script using the `system()` function instead of the shell script and I've done the `chmod 777` on all parent directories.. Yet the same problem.

Comment: The link that Kamil Maciorowski sent contains the solution of the problem.. In fact, even using c scripts, the call of `system()` brings us to the same problem..
I've tried to execute `print("%d",getegid());` which gave me the SYS's gid and not the user1's one.. Thank you all for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I'm using the shell script.. For security reasons, the SUID or the SGID aren't taken into consideration for this kind of scripts.. Also, the `system()` function in C scripts leads to the same thing.. It's better to use `execl()` so that the special rights can be taken into consideration.